# sftp uploading to non-existing directory

Tags: directory, sftp

Say I have to upload file `dir-a/dir-b/dir-c/xxx.txt` using sftp

1. Should I create the target directory first?
2. Should I open target directory before copying the file?
3. If have to create this path `dir-a/dir-b/dir-c` - is it one command or three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create the target directory first?

Usually yes. SFTP servers usually do not create parent directory. But how hard is it to try first?

> Should I open target directory before copying the file?

You do not have to. `put` command does accept a `remote-path`, which can be either absolute or relative to remote working directory.

> If have to create this path dir-a/dir-b/dir-c - is it one command or three?

These are three commands:

```
mkdir dir-a/
mkdir dir-a/dir-b/
mkdir dir-a/dir-b/dir-c
```

Comment: Thank you. While we are at it: what are the length limits on error message and path? Can I check existence of directory by getting stat on directory path?

Comment: There is no limit for error. You are getting an error in string according to the following draft: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-7 The length of path usually depends on the operating system and file system. And yes.

Comment: @Jakue. Wow,  I have to dynamically allocate rx buffer and fail protocol transaction if there is not enough memory. Thanks again.